# Spring Self Inject Into a Collection Field

Tags: java, spring, inject

In recent project, I want to jnject all beans that implements an interface into a field with type of List. The code demo like this, the bean is also implements the `Handler`.

```
@Component
class HandlerImpl implements Handler {
        @Resource
        private List<Handler> handlers;
}
```

And I find that the list contains all other beans but only not this bean itself.

We know that Spring is able to handle self inject like this

```
@Component
class HandlerImpl implements Handler {
        // this will be self
        @Resource
        private Handler handler;
}
```

So I am wondering why it did not work when the field's type is List.

I try to debug and trace into this method,

```
protected Map<String, Object> findAutowireCandidates(
                @Nullable String beanName, Class<?> requiredType, DependencyDescriptor descriptor) {

        String[] candidateNames = BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(
                        this, requiredType, true, descriptor.isEager());
        Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(candidateNames.length);
        for (Map.Entry<Class<?>, Object> classObjectEntry : this.resolvableDependencies.entrySet()) {
                Class<?> autowiringType = classObjectEntry.getKey();
                if (autowiringType.isAssignableFrom(requiredType)) {
                        Object autowiringValue = classObjectEntry.getValue();
                        autowiringValue = AutowireUtils.resolveAutowiringValue(autowiringValue, requiredType);
                        if (requiredType.isInstance(autowiringValue)) {
                                result.put(ObjectUtils.identityToString(autowiringValue), autowiringValue);
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }
        for (String candidate : candidateNames) {
                if (!isSelfReference(beanName, candidate) && isAutowireCandidate(candidate, descriptor)) {
                        addCandidateEntry(result, candidate, descriptor, requiredType);
                }
        }
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
                boolean multiple = indicatesMultipleBeans(requiredType);
                // Consider fallback matches if the first pass failed to find anything...
                DependencyDescriptor fallbackDescriptor = descriptor.forFallbackMatch();
                for (String candidate : candidateNames) {
                        if (!isSelfReference(beanName, candidate) && isAutowireCandidate(candidate, fallbackDescriptor) &&
                                        (!multiple || getAutowireCandidateResolver().hasQualifier(descriptor))) {
                                addCandidateEntry(result, candidate, descriptor, requiredType);
                        }
                }
                if (result.isEmpty() && !multiple) {
                        // Consider self references as a final pass...
                        // but in the case of a dependency collection, not the very same bean itself.
                        for (String candidate : candidateNames) {
                                if (isSelfReference(beanName, candidate) &&
                                                (!(descriptor instanceof MultiElementDescriptor) || !beanName.equals(candidate)) &&
                                                isAutowireCandidate(candidate, fallbackDescriptor)) {
                                        addCandidateEntry(result, candidate, descriptor, requiredType);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        return result;
}
```

This method is one step of the `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, it will find all matched beans. We can see that the method `isSelfReference` is called several times, and due to what, the bean itself is filtered. And in the end of the method, we can see if the field is not Collection, the bean self can be inject.

So it seems that Spring filter the bean self on purpose. I am wondering that can Spring not to filter the bean self in this case, or is there other reasons that Spring must do it.

Comment: You are still creating the bean, when injecting the dependencies into a collection field Spring will try to obtain all beans from the context. This one hasn't been added yet. Also self injection is a special usecase hence the specialized logic.

Comment: @M.Deinum In my opinion, Self Injection is one special case of Cycle Reference (there is only one bean in the cycle). And Spring can deal with this problem, Spring will cache the bean that unfinished initialization, and can be get in cycle. So why it support self injection of non-collection field, but not support collection field.

Comment: That you have to ask the Spring maintainers. But injecting 1 instance into itself or a whole collection are quite different things.